# Bind a function to a checkbox in a datagridview in the viewmodel

Tags: c#, winforms, mvvm, datagridview

Good day. I am having some problems binding a function to a checkbox inside a datagridview. I am using windows form and the mvvm model. I have a data in a datagridview and a row of checkboxes. If a checkbox is checked I want the viewmodel to excecute a function with an if statement.

Here is how my UI looks right now:

[image: Here is how my UI looks right now]

For example: If I check the first checkbox and press the "Create software quality report" button, I want the programm to excecute a function in the viewmodel. I tried getting access to the datagridview in the viewmodel, but with mvvm you shouldnt access the view from the viewmodel. How can you do this? Is it possible to have something like: (if datagridview1.checkbox1 == true) {...} in the viewmodel?

I hope that someone can give me a general direction.

Thanks in advance :)

I want to use a function inside of this function (a function in my viewmodel):

```
private void ExecuteCreateSofwareQualityReportButtonClick()
    {
        

        OpenFileDialog OpenExcel = new OpenFileDialog()
        {
            Title = "Save Excel File",
            CheckPathExists = true,
            DefaultExt = "txt",
            Filter = "Excel files (*.xls)|*.xls",
            FilterIndex = 1,
            RestoreDirectory = true
        };

        if (OpenExcel.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;

            xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(OpenExcel.FileName);


            //Excel application is stopped and the process is killed
            CloseExcelProcess(xlWorkBook, xlApp);
        }

    }
```

and here is my model:

```
public class ApplicationModel : BindableBase
{
    private Project _selectedProject;

    private Tracker _selectedTracker;

    private string _selectedSoftwareElement;

    public BindingList<Project> ProjectList { get; set; } = new BindingList<Project>();

    public BindingList<Tracker> TrackerList { get; set; } = new BindingList<Tracker>();

    public BindingList<Item> ItemList { get; set; } = new BindingList<Item>();

    public BindingList<string> SoftwareElements = new BindingList<string>();


    public Project SelectedProject
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _selectedProject; 
        }
        set 
        { 
            SetProperty(ref _selectedProject, value);  
        }
    }

    public Tracker SelectedTracker
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _selectedTracker; 
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _selectedTracker, value);
        }
    }

    public string SelectedSoftwareElement
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedSoftwareElement;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _selectedSoftwareElement, value);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Can you enter part of your code viewmodel and model code?

Comment: @MeysamAsadi of course. I will edit my question

Comment: Alternativel I can also show more on Discord if anyone has that. My Discord name is: MartinD#2253

Comment: What is the variable that binds to the DataGrid as a checkbox?

Comment: Thats what I was looking for. I dont have a variable. I am pretty new to coding and dont really know how the variable stuff in mvvm works. I looked through the internet but could only find wpf answers. I know I need to work with PropertyChanged but I really dont know how to

Comment: Sorry for being very difficult

Comment: If I give you an example, can you adapt it to your code?

Comment: I guess so. Yeah. That would be really helpful

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking. However, I am wondering what you meant in one of your comments… Meysam Asadi ask you… _”What is the variable that binds to the DataGrid as a checkbox?”_ … meaning… “what” variable/field in the collection bound to the grid is bound to the check box cells. You stated that… _”Thats what I was looking for. I dont have a variable.”_ … and this makes perfect sense.

Comment: Example… it is unknown how the grid is filled with data or if it has a data source, however… it seems fairly clear that the check box column…”Write tracker status to excel?” is a column specifically for identifying if the “tracker name” should be written to excel. I am guessing this “check box” column in the gird was added in code or the designer and is NOT part of the grids data source. The check box is simply a mechanism in the UI to signal that you want to write something to excel.

Comment: So… when you say you don’t have a variable for the check box... this makes sense as it is nothing you would want to “save” anyway. The check box is FOR the UI only. In this case… I would guess that when the button is clicked, the code would loop through the rows in the grid and check to see if the check box on that row is checked. If it is… then you would grab the “Tracker” object from that row (or what ever object is used with the grids data source) and then pass THAT object back to your model to write it to excel. Sorry if I am making the wrong assumptions.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for commenting. This is exactly what I was looking for. If the checkbox in the row of Tracker 071 is checked and the button below is pressed then I want to run a function inside the viewmodel that works with the tracker 071

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will enter an example. Match your code with it. How to use the `checkbox` in `DataGrid` and bind it to the `viewmodel`

your **Model**

```
pulic class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   private bool isCheckBox;

   public bool IsCheckBox
   {
      get { return isCheckBox; }
      set
      {
          isCheckBox = value;
          OnPropertyChange(nameof(IsCheckBox));
      }
   }
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   protected void OnPropertyChange(string propertyName)
   {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}
```

now **ViewModel**

```
public class MainViewModel
{
   public List<Model> myList { get; set; }
   public MainViewModel()
   {
      myList = new List<Model>()
      {
         new Model(){ ID = 1, Name = "name 1" IsCheckBox = true},
         new Model(){ ID = 2, Name = "name 2" IsCheckBox = false},
      };
   }
}
```

now in **MainWindow.cs**

```
public MainWindow()
{
   this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
}
```

now **MainWindow.xaml**

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding myList}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
           <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
           <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
           <DataGridCheckBoxColumn  Header="Checkbox Column" Binding="{Binding IsCheckBox, Mode=TwoWay}"/> 
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Hello, shouldnt the viewmodel and the model be switched? And I am assuming MainWindow.cs is the view

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to be clear I am not using WPF

Comment: No, they should not be changed. Each is part of the mvvm rules.